# Need to put image in the middle of a page, but text goes behind

Tags: html, css, image

I'd like to have my image in the middle of the page and text in the left and right, i use this html+css but the text goes behind the image.

The html,css:

```
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    font-family: 'Noto+Sans', serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color:  red;
  }
.centeredImage {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
left: 0; 
right: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
} 
 #malakas img {
  float: left;
}  
</style>
  </head>
<body style="overflow:hidden; margin:0">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="main" style="background-color:black">
        <div id="content">
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    <script language="javascript">
        function autoResizeDiv()
        {
        document.getElementById('main').style.height = window.innerHeight +'px';
        }
        window.onresize = autoResizeDiv;
        autoResizeDiv();
        /script>
        <div id="malakas">
  <img class="centeredImage" img src="images/eye.gif" alt="" />
    </div> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Should i use something else or css in different file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Z-index below zero (or below that of your text elements) like so:

```
.centeredImage {
      position: absolute;
      margin: auto;
      z-index:-1;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xaMJA/

Comment: in that case the style="background-color:black" should be removed from #main, so as to prevent img being covered by it

Comment: Thank you it worked, I appreciate your help and your time man. bugovicsb and m4dmike thank you too guys.

Answer (score 1):

try z-index to get the image in the background